# Литералы - константы?

Tags: java, терминология

### **Литералы**

В Java литералы применяются для представления постоянных значений в форме, удобной для восприятия. Например, число 100 является литералом. Литералы часто называют константами. Как правило, структура литералов и их использование интуитивно понятны. Они уже встречались в рассмотренных ранее примерах программ, а теперь пришло время дать им формальное определение. В Java предусмотрены литералы для всех простых типов. Способ представления литерала зависит от типа данных. Как пояснялось ранее, константы, соответствующие символам, заключаются в одинарные кавычки. Например, и 'а ', и ' % ' являются символьными константами. Целочисленные константы записываются как числа без дробной части. Например, целочисленными константами являются 10 и -100. При формировании константы с плавающей точкой необходимо указывать десятичную точку, после которой следует дробная часть. Например, 11. 123 - это константа с плавающей точкой. В Java поддерживается и так называемый экспоненциальный формат представления чисел с плавающей точкой. По умолчанию целочисленные литералы относятся к типу int. Если же требуется определить литерал типа long, после числа следует указать букву l или L. Например, 12 - это константа типа int, а 12L - константа типа long. По умолчанию литералы с плавающей точкой относятся к типу double. А для того чтобы задать литерал типа float, следует указать после числа букву f или F. Так, например, к типу float относится литерал 10.19F. Несмотря на то что целочисленные литералы по умолчанию создаются как значения типа int, их можно присваивать переменным типа char, byte, short и long. Присваиваемое значение приводится к целевому типу. Переменной типа long можно также присвоить любое значение, представленное целочисленным литералом.

Вопросы:
Литералы это значения переменных?
Почему литералы часто называют константами? Если константа это, фиксированное значение, которое не должно меняться.

Comment: А литерал и не меняется - при присвоении `a=3` меняется значение переменной-приёмника

Comment: Приведи пример, как ты _меняешь_ именно литерал?

Comment: _"указать букву 1"_ - это мне кажется, или там действительно указана единица вместо строчной буквы `L`?

Comment: @Regent, не кажется:)

Comment: Поправил, просто там в книге это как L(l).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Из википедии:

> Литералы представляют собой константы, включаемые непосредственно в
>   текст программы.

То есть

```
int someVariable = 1;
    ^              ^
    переменная     целочисленный литерал

String anotherVariable = "Привет!";
       ^                 ^
       переменная        строковый литерал
```

Вы можете присвоить любой из этих переменных другое значение, но не сможете изменить сам литерал, который был ей изначально присвоен.

Впрочем, это не всегда и не совсем верно. Например вы можете изменять значения в массиве, созданном с помощью литерала

```
int[] someArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
      ^           ^
      массив      литерал массива, состоящий из целочисленных литералов

someArray[1] = 42;
```

Answer (score 6):

Вопрос прям философский.

Литерал - это прежде всего синтаксическая конструкция. Т.е. литерал - это элемент ТЕКСТА программы.

Литерал не является значением переменной. Литерал может быть использован для того, чтобы задать значение переменной.

Затрудняюсь сказать почему, но никто не говорит "присвоить переменной литерал" или "передать литерал в функцию". Вместо этого говорят "присвоить переменной константу", "передать константу в функцию". Хотя с точки зрения текста программы первый вариант является более точным. Вот отсюда и высказывание "литералы часто называют константами".

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понял, и переменная и константа - именованные области памяти в которые можно поместить литерал. Т.е. литерал это литерал, а никакая не константа, да он неизменяем, но константой с точки зрения ЯП он от этого не становится (считаю вообще некорректно и бессмысленно говорить о его неизменяемости, так же как о неизменяемости тегов ЯП например). Просто в переменной литерал можно заменить на другой литерал, а в константе нет. После помещения литерала в переменную или константу, он становится их значением, но помещать литерал куда-то не обязательно, он может существовать и работать сам по себе, просто пока он не помещен ни в какую именованную область памяти, к нему нельзя обратиться, но его можно например вывести (echo 'строчный литерал';). Понятие литерал необходимо, чтобы понимать о чем идет речь: вот есть переменная, есть функция, есть константа, есть инструкция, есть литерал.

Answer (score 0):

Ведь понятие константы изначально рождается от изменяемости чего то, типа + и -, свет и темнота, true и false, короче инь и янь, нет понятия света - нет понятия темноты, нет понятия изменчивости нет константы, а какая литерал константа если он неизменяем "по природе".

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).