# В чем отличие константы от литерала, в Haskell?

Tags: терминология, haskell

В чем отличие константы от литерала, в языке Haskell, и если оно?

Comment: Литерал обычно - константа (в том смысле, что его значение обычно нельзя изменить), но не любая константа - литерал. Например что-то типа `const c = func();` - литералом тут и не пахнет.

Comment: В языке C, например, существует только *string literal* (например, `"string"`) и *compound literal*, в то же время `'a'`, `12`, `3.14` — это все integer constants разного вида. А это — `const int variable = 100;` — самая обычная *неизменяемая* переменная (не является константой). В разных языках будет по разному.

Comment: Вопрос не имеет отношения к функциональному программированию, не нужно добавлять эту метку.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Литералы - константы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/897130/Литералы-константы)

Comment: В haskell константа не выделяется как отдельный термин. Значение любой переменной неизменнно, и любая переменная, определенная на уровне модуля (или внутри функции, но не зависящая от формальных параметров) - по сути константа, например `pi1 = pi + 1`. А литерал это часть синтаксиса, буквальное значение: `'x'`, `"xyz"`, `1`, `1.0`

Answer (score 1):

Все функции и типы в хаскеле по умолчанию pure (кроме IO и подобного), так что они являются константными в любом случае, нет смысла вводить const как в других языках. А литералы это часть грамматик языков. В хаскеле есть весь стандартный набор в виде символов (`'A'`), листов (`"A"`) и чисел (`42`, `42.0`).